# Считывание чисел из файла в Turbo Prolog 2.0

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Есть ли возможность считать числа из файла в Turbo Prolog 2.0, если они записаны в строку?
При использовании readint происходит переход на новую строку.

Comment: считывай как строку из файла, а потом сплить эту строку на числа. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997294/10041755

Comment: вот для чисел
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368571/swi-prolog-read-file-examples